# How can I change the cache mode of an USB drive?

Tags: usb-drive, cache

I've installed ubuntu on a USB stick, which took about 2 hours. After booting from USB, the system was extreme slow, during write operations.

The problem seems to be the cache mode `[sda] Assuming drive cache: write through`.

How can I change this during and after the installation? Which is the cache mode with the fewest/laziest write operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try remounting the partition with different options, example

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw,relatime,data=writeback /dev/sda1 /
```

Another option is to pass the argument via Grub.

Comment: You can use also [`gnome-disks`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/Apps/Disks) [mount options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMUde.png), don't you?