# How can I change the cache mode of a USB drive

Tags: boot, usb, mount, cache

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a 32GB pen drive, because my hard disk stopped working. It runs okay from the pen drive, but it sometimes hangs for a few seconds during write operations (and maybe sometimes read operations too) on the pen drive. This frequently causes applications to become unresponsive for around 5 to 15 seconds (they usually turn grey during this time).

Probably enabling write-back caching will help. Does anyone know how to enable caching so that I don't suffer from occasional extremely high write (and maybe read) times?

I realize that this question is a duplicate of
[How can I change the cache mode of an USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29871/how-can-i-change-the-cache-mode-of-an-usb-drive). An answer there says:

> You can try remounting the partition with different options, example
>
> ```
> sudo mount -o remount,rw,relatime,data=writeback /dev/sda1 /
> ```
>
> Another option is to pass the argument via Grub.

Executing the above command gives this error message (in `dmesg`):

```
EXT4-fs (sdb1): Cannot change data mode on remount
```

I don't know how to pass this argument via Grub.

**Update**:

Here is my `/etc/fstab`:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdc1 during installation
UUID=75f3da54-9738-4180-8f48-fcef12d8c1ca /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/disk/by-label/DELLUTILITY /mnt/DELLUTILITY auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
/dev/disk/by-label/Recovery /mnt/Recovery auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
/dev/disk/by-label/win7 /mnt/win7 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
/dev/disk/by-label/SPARE /mnt/SPARE auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
/dev/disk/by-label/GoFlex /mnt/GoFlex auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto,x-gvfs-show,umask=002,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

- `/dev/sda` is my non-functional hard disk
- `/dev/sdb` is my pen drive.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the content of your `/etc/fstab` file on the drive you boot from.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using USB 2.0 (I hope you're not) the speed will be much less than that of a typical HDD. Anyway, since you've asked the settings are in `/etc/udisks2/IDENTIFIER.conf` where IDENTIFIER is the concatenated (and hyphenated) value of disk MODEL and SERIAL.

#### 1. Find the configuration file

You can get the MODEL and SERIAL of your disk by using the command

```
udisksctl status
```

It will report something like this

```
MODEL                     REVISION  SERIAL               DEVICE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
WDC WD1600BEVT-22ZCT0     11.01A11  WD-WXE808S69993      sda     
HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-T20N  EV02      M2L87NG3612          sr0
```

To form the file name, I'll first replace the spaces with `-` in model. It's now `WDC-WD1600BEVT-22ZCT0`. And then concatenate the serial with `-`. The result is `WDC-WD1600BEVT-22ZCT0-WD-WXE808S69993`. So, in my case the settings file is in `/etc/udisks2/WDC-WD1600BEVT-22ZCT0-WD-WXE808S69993.conf`

#### 2. Edit configuration file

In that file there should be `ini` file like entries and Section. Under `[ATA]` section, create an entry with this key-value `WriteCacheEnabled=true`.

```
# See udisks(8) for the format of this file.
[ATA]
WriteCacheEnabled=true
```

Save the file. The settings should take effect after a reboot.

Comment: I am using USB 2.0. I don't have any USB 3.0 ports.

Comment: That's making the problem i think. however check the settings

Comment: /etc/udisks2 is an empty directory (I also checked for hidden files).

Comment: Then create the files with name suggested and put the settings line in

Comment: I did that. After reboot, there is no noticeable improvement in firefox. Maybe there is a small improvement in Thunderbird. I'll check out vim soon when I code and tell you if I see an improvement there. These are probably the 3 applications I use the most.

Comment: Since, you're using USB 2.0 there might not be much improvement. the write cache should be enabled

Comment: Is there a way to check if write caching is enabled? I'm getting a feeling that nothing has changed. Maybe creating that file and putting in the settings in it didn't have any effect. Or maybe write caching was already enabled by default.

Comment: Use the command `sudo hdparm -i /dev/sda` replace /dev/sda with the exact device name of your usb drive. Yes, it is possible that write caching was enabled by default. I'm not sure. If you continue facing this problem, you better run ubuntu in Live mode with big persistence